# ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer

Tags: arcpy, arc-hydro, error-000840

I'm getting use FillSinks by ArcHydroTools but some problems are happen.

I use this code:

```
import arcpy
import ArcHydroTools
from arcpy import env
ws = env.workspace = r"C:\Users\fractal\Desktop\python_teste\projecaoMiriab2.tif"
output = "C:\Users\fractal\Documents\ArcGIS\Layers"
ArcHydroTools.FillSinks(ws, output)
```

and this error appears:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
>   Failed to execute (FillSinks).

I already tried to change my raster to format .lyr but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Have you tried creating a [Raster Layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/make-raster-layer.htm)  from your tiff and using that as the input? arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management (in_raster, out_rasterlayer, {where_clause}, {envelope}, {band_index})

Comment: I tried and didn't work too..

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format. Please use the [edit] button to revise your question with any requested clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit wonky:

`ws = env.workspace = r"C:\Users\fractal\Desktop\python_teste\projecaoMiriab2.tif"`

This code assigns the workspace, and the variable `ws`, to the folder housing your tif. So this line of code:

`ArcHydroTools.FillSinks(ws, output)`

tries to run the hydro tool with a folder as an input for a raster.

Your output looks like a folder. If so, add the name of your output raster to the output variable.

`output = "C:\Users\fractal\Documents\ArcGIS\Layers\OutRaster"`

A raster layer is different from a layer file, which you indicated when mentioning `.lyr`.

Use [Make Raster Layer](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-raster-layer.htm).

```
rast = r"C:\Users\fractal\Desktop\python_teste\projecaoMiriab2.tif"
arcpy.MakeRasterLayer_management(rast, "Miri")
ArcHydroTools.FillSinks("Miri", output)
```

Comment: I did it and another error appeared..

Comment: The another error is:

Comment: arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessing.GeoProcessorClass.Execute(String Name, IVariantArray ipValues, ITrackCancel pTrackCancel)
   at ESRI.APWR.ApHydro.ArcHydroOp.FillSinks(ApLayers& aplayers, Boolean useIsSink, Boolean fillAll, Double fillLimit, ITrackCancel trackCancel, IGPMessages messages, String& exMessage) in C:\Builds\HydroSolutions\10.2_ArcHydro\Sources\ArcHydroTools\src\ApHydro\ArcHydroOp.vb:line 64688
Failed to execute (FillSinks)

Comment: I think your output variable is also wrong. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I changed my output variable like your template and the first error "The value is not a Raster Layer" comes back.